# Regex pattern to match either none or exactly 1 of a string constant

Tags: regex

Consider this regex pattern:

```
[0-9A-Za-z](.html)*
```

The above pattern matches all of the following:

```
A
A.html
A.html.html
```

How can I change the pattern to make it match only A or A.html?

Thanks!

Comment: try this: `^[0-9A-Za-z](.html)?$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `*` by `?`

`?` means zero or one time

`*` means zero or more times

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
\w(\.html)?
```

\w is an alias for the group [a-zA-Z0-9] and makes it easier to read.

Comment: FYI, `\w` also includes underscore `_`.

Answer (score 0):

You are close. I would modify the following as follows...

```
[0-9A-Za-z](.html)?
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Updated the answer. Try that for size.

Comment: Thanks but this pattern did not match successfully with A which is required as indicated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Read the question.  Match exactly A.html or A

```
  DB<1> $a="A.html"

  DB<2> $b="A"

  DB<3> x $a =~/A(\.html)/
0  '.html'
  DB<4> x $a =~/A(\.html)?/
0  '.html'
  DB<5> x $a =~/(A(\.html)?)/
0  'A.html'
1  '.html'
  DB<6> x $b =~/(A(\.html)?)/
0  'A'
1  undef
  DB<7> $c="X.html"

  DB<8> x $c =~/(A(\.html)?)/
  empty array
```

So the answer is `/(A(\.html)?)/`

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal that may be your belief but either the question is unclear or my answer is correct!

Comment: Yes, A was just an example. Thanks anyway.